# PowerPoint Jeopardy Game

Tags: microsoft-office

I am creating a Jeopardy game using PowerPoint.  The home screen has a 3x5 grid.  Within each box is a button that his hyperlinked to a question slide.  After answering a question, we jump back to the home screen and ask another question.

Is there a way to format the hyperlinked button in each box on the home screen so it changes color when selected and keeps the changed color the rest of the game?  I tried to use an animation, but it reset each time I returned to the home screen.

Thank you,
Ken

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but this may save you a lot of time: There are a lot of people that have already made Jeopardy games using PowerPoint, and many of them are publicly posted.  Rather than reinvent the wheel, you may want to Google "jeopardy powerpoint" and see if one of these fits your requirements.  One that hides questions already selected is available at http://download.cnet.com/Powerpoint-Jeopardy/3000-2051_4-10595468.html.